# Execute specific test scenarios in a suite using Web driver

Tags: webdriver

I have a suite with more than 500 test scenarios written in Web driver. I am using TestNG framework to execute the test cases.

Could you please suggest me how to execute specific test cases from the suite like 31, 45, 68 etc?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean you want to execute the 35th <test></test> entry in testng.xml and so on?

Answer (score 0):

If you have prefaced all of your tests with @Test, then in Eclipse with TestNG plugin, you can right click on the method name, and run it as a TestNG Test.  You can also click on a class file, and only run that class.  However, if you want to run test X and test Y that are in different tests, you can press Run Configurations... and add which methods you want run.

If you don't have the TestNG plugin, you can write an XML file that has the classes, methods, groups, or suites you want to run.  It is described [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml)